# Move images after submition

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code : 
HTML :

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Inserare produse in baza de date</title>
    <style>
        table{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="subForm" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">
        <table><form action="addScript.php" methot="POST">
            <tr>
                <td>Produt name : </td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product description : </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="description" id="description"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price (USD $) : </td><td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Profile Picture : </td><td><input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Other pictures : </td><td>
                <div id="pictures" style="border:1px solid black;"><table>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="file" id="pic1" name="pic1" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="file" id="pic2" name="pic2" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td><input type="file" id="pic3" name="pic3" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  //connect to database
    $username="user";
    $password="pass";
    $database="db";
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$password,$database);
  // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  //get info from form
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $description=$_POST['description'];
  $price=$_POST['price'];
  $profilePic=$_FILES['profilepic'];
  $path="images/";

  //move picures in image/ folder and get their path
  $pic1=$_FILES['pic1']['name'];
  $pictmp=$_FILES['pic1']['tmp_name'];
  $moveResult=move_uploaded_file($pictmp, $path);

  $pic2=$_FILES['pic2']['name'];
  $pictmp=$_FILES['pic2']['tmp_name'];
  $moveResult=move_uploaded_file($pictmp, $path);

  $pic3=$_FILES['pic3']['name'];
  $pictmp=$_FILES['pic3']['tmp_name'];
  $moveResult=move_uploaded_file($pictmp, $path);

  $pic1Path=$path.$pic1;
  $pic2Path=$path.$pic2;
  $pic3Path=$path.$pic3;

//insert info in database
$sql="INSERT INTO products ( name, description, price, profile_pic, pic1, pic2, pic3)
  VALUES 
  ('$name','$description','$price',$profilePic','$pic1Path','$pic2Path','$pic3Path')";
  if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    die("ERROR".mysqli_error($con));
  }
  echo "1 product added";
  mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

And my database looks like this :

```
| ID | name | description | price | profile_pic | pic1 | pic2 | pic3|*
```

*pic comes from picture.

The problem is this : Every time I try to submit the form, I get this error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What have I done wrong?What am I missing?Is the PHP file wrong or what?

EDIT :

I found on the internet that I had set permissions to high. New I set it to 755 and I got rid of the error , but my script still doesn't work because nothing is echoed at the end.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: check your error log usually the log file is in

/var/log/apache2/error.log

or

/var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: I found this in the log :
[Wed Feb 05 14:41:23 2014] [error] [client *my ip*] SoftException in Application.cpp:259: File "/home/domain/public_html/addScript.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://domain.com/addInDatabase.php

Comment: I have permissions to both files set to 777

Comment: @Denny Bejan it is not a error of code error is server side

Comment: Yes...I have edited my post and said that I don't get the error any more, but now I get back a blank page.

Comment: And although I use method POST, it uses GET and all I put in the form is getting in the url as "addScript.php?name=....&pic3=x.jpg" Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<form action="addScript.php" methot="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: this will ensure the file to be uploaded, otherwise no $_FILES array will be created for php.

Comment: Looks like `method` is misspelled as `methot`.